# How do I initialize a value that's based on a Recursive Type Alias?

Tags: elm

How do I initialize a value that's based on a Recursive Type Alias?

```
type alias ContentProvider =
    { profile : Profile
    , topics : List Topic
    , links : Links
    , subscribers : Subscribers
    }


type Subscribers
    = Subscribers (List ContentProvider)
```

My attempt to initialize the value fails:

```
contentProvider1 : ContentProvider
contentProvider1 =
    ContentProvider profile1 topics contentProvider1Links (Subscribers [ contentProvider2, contentProvider3 ])
```

Note that the last argument is causing the error:

```
(Subscribers [ contentProvider2, contentProvider3 ])
```

> `contentProvider1` is defined in terms of itself in a sneaky way,
>   causing an infinite loop. - The following definitions depend directly
>   on each other:
>
> ```
> ┌─────┐
> │    contentProvider1
> │     ↓
> │    contentProvider2
> │     ↓
> │    contentProvider3
> └─────┘
> ```

I'm referencing this [documentation](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.18.0/hints/recursive-alias.md). However, I do not understand why I am still getting a compiler error.

**Appendix:**

```
contentProvider1 : ContentProvider
contentProvider1 =
    ContentProvider profile1 topics contentProvider1Links (Subscribers [ contentProvider2 ])


contentProvider2 : ContentProvider
contentProvider2 =
    ContentProvider profile2 topics contentProvider2Links (Subscribers [ contentProvider1, contentProvider3 ])


contentProvider3 : ContentProvider
contentProvider3 =
    ContentProvider profile3 topics contentProvider3Links (Subscribers [ contentProvider1, contentProvider2 ])
```

Comment: What are the definitions of `contentProvider` 1 and 2? It is not possible to represent a self referential cycle in a strict immutable language like elm.

Comment: @ChadGilbert I added the definitions for the contentProvider values. I'm new to Elm. However, the documentation suggests that my latest implementation should work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is syntactically correct, and prior to Elm 0.18, it would have compiled. But when you ran the program you would have ended up in either a stack overflow, an infinite loop (because of tail call recursion optimization), or a runtime exception [because of a compiler bug that has since been fixed](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/873).

Consider what the runtime would have to go through to expand `contentProvider1`:

1. Expand `contentProvider1`, which has a reference to `contentProvider2`
2. Expand `contentProvider2`, which has a reference to `contentProvider1`
3. Expand `contentProvider1`, which has a reference to `contentProvider2`
4. *and so on, to eternity*

What you are experiencing is Elm's super helpful compiler saving you from code that wouldn't have worked anyway. It is still possible to write a non-halting function ([and always will be](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), but Elm's compiler now checks for some common cases that would have otherwise blown up at runtime.

[Here is some documentation that more thoroughly explains the reasoning behind this compiler error](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/master/hints/bad-recursion.md).

Answer (score 1):

contentProvider2 and contentProvider3 need to be defined like [Chad Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857251/does-elm-allow-circular-references) said, but the issue here isn't your mutually recursive type alias, it is the [circular value reference that is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857251/does-elm-allow-circular-references). Here is a simplified example that compiles:

```
type alias ContentProvider =
    { profile : String
    , topics : List String
    , links : String
    , subscribers : Subscribers
    }

type Subscribers = 
    Subscribers (List ContentProvider)

contentProvider1 : ContentProvider
contentProvider1 =
    ContentProvider "profile" ["art", "science"] "test" (Subscribers [contentProvider2])

contentProvider2 : ContentProvider
contentProvider2 =
    ContentProvider "profile" ["art", "science"] "test" (Subscribers [])
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. But the compiler fails when contentProvider2 has a populated list of subscribers.